# Android construct json with dynamic key name and value

Tags: java, android, json

i have to construct a json request with dynamic key below is the sample i need to create, i have set "dynamic_key" from a response which i get it from other service and "dynamic_value" from user interaction, i'm not sure how to change the "dynamic_key" value everytime, could someone tell me how to do it. TIA

```
"qty":{
   "dynamic_key":"dynamic_value"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("dynamic_key", "dynamic_value");
```

Comment: And then `toString()`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Map it is in hashmap. then get all keys from that hashmap and get values on base of that keys.
For example:
Map map;
String is your key and object is your values.
Sample Code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = response.getQTYData();
        List<QTY> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
        Set mapSet = map.entrySet();
        Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();
        Map.Entry mapEntry;
        while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
            mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
            String key = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
            QTY qty = new QTY();
            qty.setKey(key);
            qty.setValue((String)map.get(key));
            mapList.add(paymentMethod);
        }
```